# How to calculate the non-linearity of an s-box?

Tags: algorithm-design, s-boxes, linear-cryptanalysis

I am struggling to understand how to calculate non-linearty of an s-box, could someone show me a detailed example? I found [“How to calculate non linearity of AES S-box?”](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19968/how-to-calculate-non-linearity-of-aes-s-box/19976#19976?newreg=f42e870fe09d4df7a44cb59950bd9161) which helped a little, but I still don't really get it. If someone could show me an example I would appreciate it.