# Affine of Inverse Sboxes

Tags: aes, s-boxes

"All 8x8 s-boxes created using Galois Field inversion plus an Affine Transform have the same non-linearity, as the Affine Transform does not change the linear or differential properties" is what this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19968/how-to-calculate-non-linearity-of-aes-s-box/19976#19976) claims.

Is there a proof of this statement?

I am unable to see how this is true. I tried to calculate the Walsh and autocorrelation spectrum but was unable to see how they are equal.

Comment: Most likely an error in your programming. The statement in that answer is a mathematical fact, thats been proved. You need to give more details for an answer to be feasible as to what you're doing wrong

Comment: you can read the "design of rijndael" or the aes proposal for details which may tell you where you are making a mistake.

Comment: I am looking for the proof of the mathematical fact. I am not writing any program.

Comment: ok fair enough, will edit answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be precise, different affine transformations following the Galois field inversion should give the same Walsh spectrum **up to a** $\pm$ **sign**, in terms of how many times each value occurs. Since an affine transformation is a linear transformation plus a constant vector addition, this is not surprising.

Don't forget linear cryptanalysis measures distance to the unbiased case (prob. 1/2) so signs of Hadamard coefficients switching between positive and negative is allowed. This is how come we can ignore the sum of the non targeted key bits modulo 2 during Linear cryptanalysis, since all they would do is switch the sign of the relevant coefficient.

Let 
$$L_{a,b} := \sum_{x \in V_n} (-1)^{a \cdot x \oplus b \cdot S(x)}$$

where $V_n$ is the n dimensional binary vector space. Let $A x+c$ be an affine map where the linear part $x\mapsto Ax$ is full rank and thus invertible. It is then a simple matter of algebra to prove the result:
$$L_{a,b}' := \sum_{x \in V_n} (-1)^{a \cdot x 
\oplus b \cdot (A \cdot S(x)\oplus c)}$$
by a change of basis.

Even better, in "The Design of Rijndael" by Daemen and Rijmen, (See  [here](https://autonome-antifa.org/IMG/pdf/Rijndael.pdf), Appendix A.1 onwards, provided for personal research use only) there is a coordinate free approach using trace functions on the finite field to show this.

Similar comments apply for the correlation spectrum.

Comment: I think I am missing something here as I was not able to figure it out by reading the appendix or by your proof. Could you explain in a bit more detail.                                                                                                               I also wrote some sage code where I found an affine of an inverse in a galois field which was unbalanced and had zero non linearity while others gave the same properties as AES.  So I think that balancedness has to be a prerequisite.

Comment: Yes, since you want a one to one map, its automatically balanced.